# c++ array code error

Tags: c++

The code won't run, says the "return value" is wrong where it says return `found[i]=letter`, and the `srand time` is also showing error. I am not sure how to fix it? Perhaps put `found[i]` in `main()` and put `return 1?`? And not sure how to get the `srand` to work properly?

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 
void getarray(char [], int); 
void printa(char [],int ); 
void search(char [],int, char); 
void main() { 
    srand(time(0)); //1-declare char letter=' '; 
    char guess[7]; 
    char found[7]={letter}; 
    int res=0; 
    char answer='Y';
}
//2-init
getarray(guess,7); 
//3- processing 
printa(guess,7);
while(answer == 'Y')
{
    cout << "enter a letter";
    cin >>letter;
    search(guess,7,letter); 
    if (res != -1)
        printa(found,7);

    cout <<" do you want to continue(Y/N)?"<<endl;
    cin >>answer;
}

//printing
system("pause");
}
void getarray(char a[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        a[i]= 65 + rand()%26;
}
void printa(char a[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout << " the letter " << i+1 << " is "<<a[i]<<endl;
}
void search(char a[],int n, char key)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if ( a[i]== key)
            return Found[i]=={letter}; 
}
```

Comment: @user1484705 - this is not correct way to upload code, you can make an edit in your code itself and paste code there.

Comment: [`void main`](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main)

Comment: you can hit the 'edit' link and just adapt your post, see this: http://imgur.com/Si4pP

Comment: k found it and put it up again thnx

Comment: so about found[i]=letter... do i put that above main instead? and perhaps do return 1 return -1 or res=search...? been trying different things but it just wont run :/

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have an extra `}` that terminates your function a bit too early.

```
void main() {
   srand(time(0)); //1-declare char letter=' '; 
   char guess[7]; 
   char found[7]={letter}; 
   int res=0; 
   char answer='Y';
}   <--- This seems not correct

// 2-init
getarray(guess,7);
```

The rest of the code then appears to be *outside* of the function, and that confuses the compiler.